# Threads and tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, tcl

I've heard that threads in Python are not easy to handle and they become more tangled with tkinter.

I have the following problem. I have two classes, one for the GUI and another for an infinite process. First, I start the GUI class and then the infinite process' class. I want that when you close the GUI, it also finishes the infinite process and the program ends.

A simplified version of the code is the following:

```
import time, threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

finish = False

class tkinterGUI(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):  
        global finish
        #Main Window
        self.mainWindow = Tk()
        self.mainWindow.geometry("200x200")
        self.mainWindow.title("My GUI Title")
        #Label
        lbCommand = Label(self.mainWindow, text="Hello world", font=("Courier New", 16)).place(x=20, y=20)
        #Start
        self.mainWindow.mainloop()
        #When the GUI is closed we set finish to "True"
        finish = True

class InfiniteProcess(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global finish
        while not finish:
            print("Infinite Loop")
            time.sleep(3)

GUI = tkinterGUI()
GUI.start()
Process = InfiniteProcess()
Process.start()
```

When I click in the close button (in the upper right corner) the following error appears in the console:

```
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

I don't know why it happens or what it means.

Comment: Your simplified version works ok for me... There must be something you forgot to add that is causing your problem

Comment: @mguijarr I read in google that this error is more common in Window, what's your SO? Mine is Windows 7 x64. Maybe windows is the problem :/

Answer (score 23):

[All Tcl commands need to originate from the same thread](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1527).  Due to `tkinter`'s
dependence on Tcl, it's generally necessary to make all `tkinter` gui statements
originate from the same thread. The problem occurs because 
`mainWindow` is instantiated in the `tkinterGui` thread, but -- because `mainWindow` is an attribute of `tkinterGui` -- is not destroyed until `tkinterGui` is destroyed in the main thread.

The problem can be avoided by not making `mainWindow` an attribute of `tkinterGui`
-- i.e. changing `self.mainWindow` to `mainWindow`. This allows  `mainWindow` to be destroyed when the `run` method ends *in the `tkinterGui` thread*. However, often you can avoid threads entirely by using `mainWindow.after` calls instead:

```
import time, threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def infinite_process():
    print("Infinite Loop")
    mainWindow.after(3000, infinite_process)


mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.geometry("200x200")
mainWindow.title("My GUI Title")
lbCommand = Label(mainWindow, text="Hello world", font=("Courier New", 16)).place(x=20, y=20)
mainWindow.after(3000, infinite_process)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

---

If you want to define the GUI inside a class, you can still do so:

```
import time, threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.geometry("200x200")
        master.title("My GUI Title")
        lbCommand = Label(master, text="Hello world", 
                          font=("Courier New", 16)).place(x=20, y=20)

def tkinterGui():  
    global finish
    mainWindow = Tk()
    app = App(mainWindow)
    mainWindow.mainloop()
    #When the GUI is closed we set finish to "True"
    finish = True

def InfiniteProcess():
    while not finish:
        print("Infinite Loop")
        time.sleep(3)

finish = False
GUI = threading.Thread(target=tkinterGui)
GUI.start()
Process = threading.Thread(target=InfiniteProcess)
Process.start()
GUI.join()
Process.join()
```

or even simpler, just use the main thread to run the GUI mainloop:

```
import time, threading
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.geometry("200x200")
        master.title("My GUI Title")
        lbCommand = Label(master, text="Hello world", 
                          font=("Courier New", 16)).place(x=20, y=20)

def InfiniteProcess():
    while not finish:
        print("Infinite Loop")
        time.sleep(3)

finish = False
Process = threading.Thread(target=InfiniteProcess)
Process.start()

mainWindow = Tk()
app = App(mainWindow)
mainWindow.mainloop()
#When the GUI is closed we set finish to "True"
finish = True
Process.join()
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot! You are a master!

Comment: But sometimes you NEED to make mainWindow as an attribute, for example, if you want to use:
self.mainWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)

When you define the function quit() and you write:
self.mainWindow.destroy()
self.mainWindow.quit()

mainWindow must be an attribute, otherwise the function quit won't recognize mainWindow.

Comment: You can still use a class; just don't make the instance an attribute of the `threading.Thread`. I've added some code above to suggest how.

Comment: Strictly, Tcl can do multithreading and Tk can too (provided they're built with the right options) but you've got to keep an entire context per thread. The threading model is _totally_ different to that of Python — it's much more like having a separate OS process — though that does mean that Tcl uses global locks far more sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

The fix here is simple, but hard to discover:

**Call `mainWindow.quit()` immediately after `mainwindow.mainloop()`**, so that the cleanup happens on the same thread as the one that created the tk UI, rather than on the main thread when python exits.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a universal solution. I have code exhibiting this same problem (Tcl_AsyncDelete error) and adding `mainWindow.quit()` after `mainWindow.mainloop()` has no effect.

Comment: @BryanOakley yep, same issue: in trying to avoid Tcl_AsyncDelete I have found `.quit()` unnecessary on Python 2.7.14, and ineffective on Python 3.6.3.  Haven't got a solution yet.