# Running a background thread reading serial data with tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial

I am working on a python gui with tkinter that its purpose is to read serial data from an arduino and also send data to the arduino. the difference between the sending and receiving processes is that the sending is invoked by pressing the different gui buttons only when the user wants, but the receiving is operated with a thread.
i read a lot of Q&A here about this issue and I saw answers talking about multithreading and threadpool and more... but at this time I don't want to get into that. so what I would like to do is create a thread that reads the data from the arduino lets say every 0.5 sec and each time the user presses a button for sending data to the arduino the buttons callback will first stop the thread then send the wanted data and when he finishes he will start the receiving thread again. so my question is is it possible to do what I want and what problems should I expect?

i should also mention that the receiving thread shows the data on widgets that only he can change, but the thread and the other button functions use the same serial transmit and receive functions that I built... but as I mentioned I "don't allow" them to use those functions together...

thank you a lot in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Couldnt that be enough for your case ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63118515/13629335

Comment: The problem that you will face will be that you want to have widgets edited by another thread. There are solutions for, but I think the `after` method should be enough for you.

Comment: first try to write it. And later show it in question. It will be better then your description.