# tkinter gui for spammer after pressing start

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, crash

i am doing a tkinter gui for message spammer. It works but when i press start button it the gui crash..
here is the code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

window = Tk()

window.title("message spammer")


def clicked():
    message = "grc"
    keyboard = Controller()

    time.sleep(5)

    for num in range(100):
        for letter in message:
            keyboard.press(letter)
            keyboard.release(letter)
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(1)


btn = Button(window, text="Start", command=clicked)

btn.grid(column=0, row=0)

window.geometry("350x350")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: would it be okay if you share what is `Controller()` did you made that class?

Comment: Dont use `time.sleep` use the `after(ms, func)` method instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a timer using tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400262/how-to-create-a-timer-using-tkinter)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63118430/create-a-main-loop-with-tkinter/63118515#63118515

Comment: Atlas435 i replaced that time.sleep(1) with window.after(ms=1000), but gui still crash :D but thnx for responding

Comment: Basically you will have to restructure your code to make the `after()` work correctly. It also takes the function name as argument