# Countdown clock not updating in a multi-frame tkinter app

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm in the progress of writing a python app to show a countdown clock in one window, and a video in another (haven't started integrating the video part yet).

However, the countdown clock I have written doesn't update, and only shows the initial countdown time when the app was launched. I need it to update around every 500ms.

This is the area of interest in my code `PageOne` & `show_clock`. PageOne is the display frame which should update to show a live clock countdown.

EDIT: Code has been updated since original post. Now I don't get the clock label updating at all. I'm experiencing the following errors:

```
Line 73 : Statement seems to have no effect
It looks like the statement doesnt have (or at least seems to) any effect.
Line 108 : Name 'show_time' is not defined
```

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    fnt = font.Font(family='Quicksand Medium', size=30)
    
    self.txt = tk.StringVar()
    self.show_time
    
    lbl = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.txt, font=fnt, foreground="black", background="#FFFFDD")
    lbl.pack()
    button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
    button.pack()

def show_time(self):
    endTime = datetime.datetime(2029, 7, 20, 16, 0, 0)
    # Get the time remaining until the event
    remainder = endTime - datetime.datetime.now()
    # remove the microseconds part
    remainder = remainder - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=remainder.microseconds)

    yrs = remainder.days // 365
    yrsTxt = ' years, '
    if yrs == 1:
        yrsTxt = ' year, '

    days = remainder.days % 365
    daysTxt = ' days,'
    if days == 1:
    daysTxt = ' day,'

    timeTxt = str(remainder).split(',')[1]

    # Show the time left
    global myClock
    myClock = str(yrs) + yrsTxt + str(days) + daysTxt + timeTxt
    
    # Show the time left
    self.txt.set(f"{yrs} {yrsTxt}, {days} {daysTxt}, {timeTxt}")
    
    self.after(1000, show_time)
```

Comment: You've posted too much code. Please try to narrow the code down to a [mcve]. That being said, when you do something like `self.after(500, show_time())`, it immediately calls `show_time()` rather than waiting 500ms. `after` requires a callable.

Comment: I have edited the code to be more concise. So, how would I use after to loop rather than call once?

Comment: [Have look at this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63118515/13629335)

Comment: So I've updated the code to call update_clock which repeats, which updates the label StringVar. However, it still doesn't update?

Comment: I think I've narrowed down the issue, please see my edit in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use instance variable instead of local variable if the variable will be accessed across functions.  Also you need to prefix `self.` when calling class methods.

Below is the modified code:

```py
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller
        fnt = font.Font(family='Quicksand Medium', size=30)

        self.txt = tk.StringVar() # use instance variable instead
        lbl = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.txt, font=fnt,
                       foreground="black", background="#FFFFDD")
        lbl.pack()

        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

        self.update_clock() # start updating clock


    def update_clock(self):
        self.show_time()
        self.after(1000, self.update_clock)


    def show_time(self): # added self argument
        endTime = datetime.datetime(2029, 7, 20, 16, 0, 0)
        # Get the time remaining until the event
        remainder = endTime - datetime.datetime.now()
        # remove the microseconds part
        remainder -= datetime.timedelta(microseconds=remainder.microseconds)

        yrs, days = divmod(remainder.days, 365)
        yrsTxt = "years" if yrs > 1 else "year"
        daysTxt = "days" if days > 1 else "day"
        timeTxt = str(remainder).split(',')[1]

        # Show the time left
        self.txt.set(f"{yrs} {yrsTxt}, {days} {daysTxt}, {timeTxt}")
```

Note that you can combine `update_clock()` and `show_time()` into one function for your case.

Comment: Hi, I've implimented your changes, but I'm getting a lot of warnings. Please see the main post.

Comment: Note that your code has indentation issue.  Also `update_clock()` and `show_time()` are class methods in my code.  Make sure you have followed my changes.