# while loop is making my customtkinter app freeze. how can i make a better function that wont freeze the app?

Tags: python, while-loop, freeze, customtkinter

I am making a game using the customtkinter library
the game is a clicker tycoon game that involves beans. quite similar to cookie clicker.
below is the entire code

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from customtkinter import CTkImage,CTkButton,CTkLabel
#from PIL import Image
import time as t

# stores money
money = 0
# variables for bean generation
beans = 0
click = 1
#toggles bean collection
toggle=False
#Application
class BeanApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # sets window and frames
        self.title("Bean Tycoon")
        self.geometry("500x500+700+200")

        #click modes
        multiplier_lbl=CTkLabel(self,text= "Multipliers")
        multiplier_lbl.place(x=250,y=1,anchor="n",)
        def xOne():#x1 multiplier toggle
            global click
            click=1
            one_click_mode_btn.configure(state="disabled")
            two_click_mode_btn.configure(state="enable")
            click_multiplyer_lbl.configure(text=f"  Beans/click: x{click}   ")
        def xTwo():#x2 multiplier toggle
            global click
            click=2
            one_click_mode_btn.configure(state="enable")
            two_click_mode_btn.configure(state="disabled")
            click_multiplyer_lbl.configure(text=f"  Beans/click: x{click}   ")

        one_click_mode_btn= CTkButton(self,text="x1",width=20,height=10,command=xOne,state="disabled")
        one_click_mode_btn.place(x=145,y=25,anchor="nw")
        two_click_mode_btn=CTkButton(self, text="x2",width=20,height=10,command=xTwo,state="disabled")
        two_click_mode_btn.place(x=173,y=25,anchor="nw")
        click_multiplyer_lbl=CTkLabel(self,text=f"  Beans/click: x{click}   ")
        click_multiplyer_lbl.place(x=3,y=45,anchor="nw",)
        # Bean generator
        #beanbtn = CTkImage(Image.open("Pictures\TheBean.png"),size=(200,200))
        bean_amt_lbl = CTkLabel(self,text= f"  Beans: {beans}  ",)
        bean_amt_lbl.place(x=3,y=5,anchor="nw")
        def clicked():
            global beans
            global click
            beans += click
            bean_amt_lbl.configure(text= f"  Beans: {beans}  ")

        sell_beans_btn = CTkButton(self,text= "",image=None, command= clicked,width=180,height=180) 
        sell_beans_btn.place(x=250,y=330, anchor="s")
        # Sell Beans
        money_amt_lbl = CTkLabel(self,text=f"  Money: ${money}  ", )
        money_amt_lbl.place(x=3,y=25,anchor='nw')
        def sell():
            global money
            global beans
            while beans >0:
                money = money+beans
                beans = 0
                bean_amt_lbl.configure(text=f"  Beans: {beans}  ")
                money_amt_lbl.configure(text=f"  Money: ${money  }")
                
        sell_bean_btn = CTkButton(self,text="Sell Beans",image=None, command=sell)
        sell_bean_btn.place(x=250,y=360,anchor='s')
        #2 times multiplier
        def d_b_u():#double_bean_upgrade
            global click,money
            if money>=100:
                click=2
                money=money-100
                money_amt_lbl.configure(text=f"  Money: ${money  }")
                double_bean_upgrade_btn.configure(state="disabled")
                two_click_mode_btn.configure(state="disabled")
                one_click_mode_btn.configure(state="enable")
                click_multiplyer_lbl.configure(text=f"  Beans/click: x{click}   ")
        #automatic bean collector
        def a_b_c_u():#automatic_bean_collector_upgrade
            global beans,money,toggle
            if money>=20:
                money=money-20
                money_amt_lbl.configure(text=f"  Money: ${money  }")
                auto_collect_bean_btn.configure(state="disabled")
                while beans >=0 :
                    beans=beans+1
                    bean_amt_lbl.configure(text=f"  Beans: {beans}  " )
                    t.sleep(3)
                    print(beans) 
                               
        #Shop
        shop_lbl= CTkLabel(self,text="Shop")
        shop_lbl.place(x=425,y=5,anchor="nw")
        double_bean_upgrade_btn = CTkButton(self,text="Bean Doubler\n$100",command=d_b_u,width=20,corner_radius=20)
        double_bean_upgrade_btn.place(x=390,y=30,anchor="nw")
        auto_collect_bean_btn = CTkButton(self,text="Auto Collect 1\n$200",command=a_b_c_u,width=20,corner_radius=20)
        auto_collect_bean_btn.place(x=390,y=70,anchor="nw")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = BeanApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

the game involves an incremental counter that runs in the background, the loop is toggled via a button.
however when the loop activates it freezes the application. how can this be fixed?

EDIT: I hashtagged the image library and image function since it does not effect the code in the slightest as of now.

EDIT 2:How do i properly implement Threads? i dont think i did this right...

> ```
>   #automatic bean collector
> ```

```
    def b_c_():
        global beans
        while beans >=0 :
                beans=beans+1
                bean_amt_lbl.configure(text=f"  Beans: {beans}  " )
                t.sleep(3)
                print(beans) 
    bean_collector=Thread(target= b_c_)
    def a_b_c_u():#automatic_bean_collector_upgrade
        global beans,money,toggle
        if money>=20:
            money=money-20
            money_amt_lbl.configure(text=f"  Money: ${money  }")
            auto_collect_bean_btn.configure(state="disabled")
            bean_collector.run()
```

Edit 3: Removed as it strayed from the original problem

Comment: Have you looked into using threads / multiprocessing?

Comment: no i havent, mostly because i dont know what threads are other that their use in multiprocessing.

Comment: Processes and threads are related, but different. Threads run within the context of one OS process.... Both can help un-block a UI, however.

Comment: You might want to see the example in this post  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26703844/2308683

Comment: i dont think i still understand how to properly implement it in my use case. i just have more questions now

Comment: Not fully sure, but you can use the `.run()` (or stop the thread) functions from the `target` functions you've set on the buttons. If you want the thread to always run (e.g. the automatic money one), then you should put that after `app.mainloop()` since its a separate "loop" happening. The only issue is that global variable are a bad idea (especially with threads), and you need other functions that would actually update the gui.

Comment: Also, the `sell` action doesn't need a loop, for example. You just zero-out the beans. Add to the money, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the the loop into another thread so that the user interface does not freeze. You can use the `thread` library.

```py
import thread

def foo(args):
  # loop logic

thread.start_new_thread(foo, (args))
```

Comment: alright, and i can activate the thread with a button correct?

Comment: also, the thread library does not show and pip cannot find the library. i am using python 3.11 if that helps

Comment: @T.E.GStudios Thread library is built-in. https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to not block a UI is to pass around functions when the UI actually **has** to be updated, not use loops, at all, or very minimally.

You also have global state, which is not recommended. To solve both, add some more classes.

```
class Bank:
  def __init__(self):
    self.money = 0

  def deposit(self, amount, handler=None)
    ''' accepts optional function with the amount deposited '''
    self.money += amount
    if handler:
      handler(amount)

  def withdraw(self, amount, handler=None)
    ''' accepts optional function with the amount withdrawn '''
    if self.money >= amount:
      self.money -= amount
      if handler:
        handler(amount)
    else:
      print('error: not enough money available')
```

```
class BeanCounter:
  def __init__(self, amount=0):
    self.amount = amount

  def increment(self, handler=None):
    ''' accepts optional function called after one bean added '''
    self.amount += 1
    if handler:
      handler()
```

Then update the app constructor and define some functionality with the above
functions

```
class BeanApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, bank, bean_counter):
      super().__init__()
      # sets window and frames
      self.title("Bean Tycoon")

      self.bank = bank
      self.bean_counter = bean_counter

      # add labels 

    def bean_label_updater(self):
      ''' updates the bean label with the current amount '''  
      self.bean_amt_lbl.configure(text= f"  Beans: {self.bean_counter.amount}  ")

    def on_click(self):
      self.bean_counter.increment(bean_label_updater)
    # TODO: button target=on_click

    def on_click_sell(self):
      self.bank.deposit(self.bean_counter.amount)  # times amount per bean ; todo: add bank label updater function
      self.bean_counter.amount = 0
      self.bean_label_updater()
```

And then

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  bank = Bank()
  bean_counter = BeanCounter()

  app = BeanApp(bank, bean_counter)
  app.mainloop()
```

This wont fully solve the "automatic collector" from blocking the UI, but it at least points you in a general start for separating your "state/model" from your "view"

One solution, is to create a threaded wrapper around the beancounter class like this, then start that on the associated action.

```
class BeanDoubler(Thread):
  def __init__(self, bean_counter, update_func=None):
    self.bean_counter = bean_counter
    self.update_func = update_func
  def run(self):
    while True:
      # use a for loop to increment over the amount (thereby doubling)
      for _ in range(self.bean_counter.amount):
        self.bean_counter.increment(self.update_func)
```

(code has not been tested, sorry if there's typos)

Comment: OMG This helps tremendously, ill be sure to study up on these functions for future projects. Thank you soo much.

Comment: well now that i am implementing the code there are a few errors being presented. just one question. does BeanCounter go under the bank class or is it outside of the classes?

Comment: There are three separate classes. None are nested within each other. I see now I put `def` instead of `class` sorry about that

Comment: one last question, the handler functions, i assume they connect the UI elements such as buttons to the main classes is that correct?

Comment: They can be used that way, yes, but they are generic callback function handles

Comment: I see, is there any way I can message you privately to discuss this further or do you know of anyone who may help me? there are still a few errors that I found that I need help with working out. ill update this thread accordingly as to help solve the initial problem.

Comment: refer to edit 3 so you can see what im talking about

Comment: I suggest creating a new post rather than edit the existing one, but 1) My `BeanDoubler` does not exist `BeanCounter`. Neither should `BeanApp`. 2) You'll need to show the stacktrace or add more logging to see where recursion happened

Comment: ill keep this in mind, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @T.E.GStudios Edited the answer with an indentation fix

Answer (score 0):

All I seem to get now is a defined object with no attributes to the answer I was given. I am now having trouble passing the objects and their attributes into `class BeanApp()` as shown here

[image].

I somewhat understand where I went wrong which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76264684/21627934). thankfully the UI now runs well.

To elaborate, `bank` and `bean_doubler` in `class BeanApp(self,bank,bean_doubler)`
are empty variables when they should, to my understanding, be connected to the `class Bank()` and `class BeanDoubler()` to then use the functions in them in the window that class BeanApp()` initializes.