# i dont know what caused this Recursion Error

Tags: python, recursion, python-multithreading, customtkinter, recursionerror

I am making a customtkinter game that is basically Cookie Clicker but themed around beans. and by suggestions from another thread I added Threading, which I'm having a hard time implementing, and multiple classes, which I don't understand how to make the data pass into my main class. regardless these attempts has gave me a recursion error

This is the entire program so far

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from customtkinter import CTkImage,CTkButton,CTkLabel
from PIL import Image
import time as t
from threading import Thread


class Bank():
    def __init__(self):
        self.money=0
    def deposit(self,amount,handler=None):
        self.money += amount
        if handler:
            handler(amount)
    def withdraw(self, amount, handler=None):
        if self.money >= amount:
           self.money -= amount
        if handler:
            handler(amount)
        else:
            print('error: not enough money available')
class BeanCounter():
    def __init__(self, amount=0):
        self.amount = amount

    def increment(self, handler=None):
        ''' accepts optional function called after one bean added '''
        self.amount += 1
        if handler:
            handler()
class BeanDoubler(Thread,BeanCounter):
    def __init__(self,update_func=None):
        self.bean_counter = BeanCounter()
        self.update_func = update_func
    def run(self):
        while True:
        # use a for loop to increment over the amount (thereby doubling)
            for _ in range(self.bean_counter.amount):
                self.bean_counter.increment(self.update_func)

class BeanApp(ctk.CTk,Bank,BeanCounter):
  def __init__(self):
        # sets window and frames
        self.title("Bean Tycoon")


        #click modes
        multiplier_lbl=CTkLabel(self,text= "Multipliers")
        multiplier_lbl.place(x=250,y=1,anchor="n",)
        

        one_click_mode_btn= CTkButton(self,text="x1",width=20,height=10,command=None,state="disabled")
        one_click_mode_btn.place(x=145,y=25,anchor="nw")
        two_click_mode_btn=CTkButton(self, text="x2",width=20,height=10,command=None,state="disabled")
        two_click_mode_btn.place(x=173,y=25,anchor="nw")
        click_multiplyer_lbl=CTkLabel(self,text=f"  Beans/click: x{None}   ")
        click_multiplyer_lbl.place(x=3,y=45,anchor="nw",)
        # Bean generator
        beanbtn = CTkImage(Image.open("None"),size=(200,200))
        def on_click():
            BeanCounter.increment(bean_label_updater())
   
        bean_amt_lbl = CTkLabel(self,text= f"  Beans: {None}  ",)
        bean_amt_lbl.place(x=3,y=5,anchor="nw")
        def bean_label_updater():
           bean_amt_lbl.configure(text= f"  Beans: {BeanCounter.amount}  ")
        sell_beans_btn = CTkButton(self,text= "",image=beanbtn, command= on_click,width=180,height=180) 
        sell_beans_btn.place(x=250,y=330, anchor="s")
        # Sell Beans
        money_amt_lbl = CTkLabel(self,text=f"  Money: ${None}  ", )
        money_amt_lbl.place(x=3,y=25,anchor='nw')
        def on_click_sell(self):
            Bank.deposit(BeanCounter.amount)  # times amount per bean ; todo: add bank label updater function
            BeanCounter.amount = 0
            
                
        sell_bean_btn = CTkButton(self,text="Sell Beans",image=None, command=on_click_sell)
        sell_bean_btn.place(x=250,y=360,anchor='s')
        #2 times multiplier
        
        
        #Shop
        shop_lbl= CTkLabel(self,text="Shop")
        shop_lbl.place(x=425,y=5,anchor="nw")
        double_bean_upgrade_btn = CTkButton(self,text="Bean Doubler\n$100",command=None,width=20,corner_radius=20)
        double_bean_upgrade_btn.place(x=390,y=30,anchor="nw")
        auto_collect_bean_btn = CTkButton(self,text="Auto Collect 1\n$200",command=None,width=20,corner_radius=20)
        auto_collect_bean_btn.place(x=390,y=70,anchor="nw")


if __name__ == "__main__":
  bank = Bank()
  bean_counter = BeanCounter()
  beandoubler = BeanDoubler()
  app = BeanApp()
  app.mainloop()
```

this is the error that pulled up
[recursion error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfVlF.png)

can anyone tell me where I went wrong and help me fix it?

what should come up is a  customtkinter window that looks similar to this [first window iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9TMC.png)
the code that popped up that window kept freezing the application when i ran it, which is how I got to the current problem that I'm facing.

Edit 1: I have figured I should share the
[full callback log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZESN8.png)

Comment: Just an aside, you seem to want to treat your classes and their members as instances as well as singletons.  You might want to verify that when you do `BeanCounter.increment(bean_label_updater())` that is actually does what you hope

Comment: hm could explain why self did not work in Class BeanApp for BeanCounter and Bank classes. which was somthing i noticed while debugging

Comment: also keep in mind im pretty new to programing, so if structuring them as instances and singletons is not a good way id appreciate guidance to making it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the traceback, and you'll find that your error is only coming from `self.title("Bean Tycoon")` line, so has nothing to do with the remainder of the code...

---

In any case, your classes don't need multi-inheritance

Replace

```
class BeanDoubler(Thread,BeanCounter):
```

with

```
class BeanDoubler(Thread):
```

A BeanCounter *instance* is passed **into** the `__init__` constructor of that class, as [shown in my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76058141/2308683)

Similar for `BeanApp`. It only needs to be a `ctk.CTk` class, and the `__init__` is different for that. Plus, you've removed `super().__init__()` for some reason

---

Then, it is not `BeanCounter.increment(bean_label_updater())`, it is `self.bean_counter.increment(bean_label_updater)`...

1. You use an instance to call a function, not a class
2. You do not pass the return value of a function call into `increment`, only the function name / handle. It's the responsibility of `increment` to actually call the function via this section

   ```
    if handler:
        handler()
   ```

Similarly, `BeanCounter.amount` is not a valid accessor. You should use `self.bean_counter.amount` since it is an instance field, as was also written in my last answer.

---

You have defined functions within your `__init__` of the BeanApp, which is generally not recommended. Define all functions at the class level, rather than within other functions. Then `self` will reference the `BeanApp` instance, where you can access `self.bank` and `self.bean_counter`, after updating your `__init__` parameters and `__main__` section.

Comment: the one problem i had with the previous answer is `self.bean_counter.amount` and related fuctions in both `class Bank`and `class BeanDoubler` had no proper inheritance within `class BeanApp` which in turn none of the functions worked. so i tried fixing it as to get no errors in the code. clearly i just made it worse. ill revert my code back to your answer and try again with a different approach with these explanations in mind

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `self` attribute access doesn't need inheritance, but you do need to define the variables, through `__init__` constructor, which you missed copying from my previous post https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=__init__#class-objects

Comment: my class structure is on point with the tutorial you sent me. and i copied and pasted your code a couple of times just to make sure it was all correct. still, the objects are not connected with the previous classes. i use Pylance on VS Code and the objects appear white with a tool tip that says `(function)bean_counter: Any` which from my understanding shows that the program recognizes that the function exists but has no attributes. which is what ive been trying to pass into `class BeanApp`

Comment: imma take this back to [my first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267371/21627934) as this is getting off topic. i do understand where i went wrong originally and i hope i can get these errors resolved

Answer (score 0):

so i found i was missing the `super().__init__` constructor so now the UI runs but im now left with the object inheritance errors. i will be closing this thread and going back to [my original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76057068/while-loop-is-making-my-customtkinter-app-freeze-how-can-i-make-a-better-functi/76058141#76058141)

i guess while debugging the original answer i have accidently removed the `super().__init__`